# Automated zabbix 2.0 install

Tags: zabbix

I'm trying to automate the install of the Zabbix server. I had  used the 1.8 Ubuntu packages before but am now compiling from source to get the 2.0.4 version. The install instructions appear to use an interactive PHP interface but I'd like to get this automated.

Can I just setup the DB form the SQL files and copy the config files as required? Or is there perhaps an automated installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactive PHP interface just creates file `zabbix.conf.php` If you copy this file, and then you won't need interactive installer.

And a little hiht: to get properly conffigured package, with dependencies, debconf automation of some actions and so on, you may just backport packages from Debian Unstable

Comment: Just creating the config file seems to be enough (though I found a template in the src directory instead of going through the installer).

Answer (score 0):

For me the autoinstallation did not point apache2 at the zabbix directory.

I had to create
int zabbix # ln -s /usr/share/zabbix /var/www/
int zabbix # ls -al !$
ls -al /var/www/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb  4 01:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Feb  4 00:59 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  177 Feb  4 01:01 index.html
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   17 Feb  4 01:28 zabbix -> /usr/share/zabbix